# How to set a view's outlets' values from within another class

Tags: swift, xcode

In xcode, If we have a view controller that has some subviews' (eg: label) outlets, and we want to change its text from the AppDelegate.swift class whenever an app is becoming active after suspended, How can this be done? I have tried making an instance of this view controller class from the AppDelegate class, but that didn't work because it made another view instance instead of the view itself, and we can't set the outlet as static. I have also thought of making a static ViewController property observer, but since it is static I still can't set the outlet from inside it. So, how can we do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want - is [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/notificationcenter). In your view controller add observer which will change your label's text or whatever. From AppDelegate method post notification. If you need an example, I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

> If we have a view controller that has some subviews' (eg: label) outlets, and we want to change its text from the AppDelegate.swift class whenever an app is becoming active after suspended, How can this be done?

1. Don't. Never speak directly to another class's outlets. Give that class a *method* that you can call where *that* class will respond to the calling of that method by speaking to its *own* outlet.

> I have tried making an instance of this view controller class from the AppDelegate class, but that didn't work because it made another view instance

2. Correct. You need to *get a reference* to the *existing* instance of the other class. To do that, you need to know your own view controller hierarchy / structure or else provide one class with a delegate / reference to the other class at the time of creation.

Comment: I can't give the class a method and call it from outside because it will also make another instance and it can't be static as well

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do solution n.2 in more details please?